# Check for changes/new messages in IMAP4?

Tags: imap

I essentially want to do the equivalent of what was asked in this question: [How to retrieve only new emails using POP3 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960295/how-to-retrieve-only-new-emails-using-pop3-protocol/5960755#5960755) but for IMAP4 instead of POP3, so same premise but completely different answer.

If I've already downloaded all the message headers and UIDs and so forth previously and have that information at my disposal, how can I efficiently find out what messages are new/changed/deleted so I can download just those messages without re-downloading all the seen messages?

Currently I'm `FETCH`ing the `UID`'s for each local message ID and seeing if any UID's are new or missing, and then `FETCH`ing the `RFC822` data for each new UID. But in practice, this seems terribly slow, so I'd like to see if I can find a more efficient way to identify new/changed messages.

```
Sent 5/7/2014 9:42:08 AM: C5 FETCH 1 (UID)<EOL>
Recv 5/7/2014 9:42:08 AM: * 1 FETCH (UID 46987)<EOL>C5 OK Fetch completed.<EOL>
Sent 5/7/2014 9:42:08 AM: C6 FETCH 2 (UID)<EOL>
Recv 5/7/2014 9:42:08 AM: * 2 FETCH (UID 46989)<EOL>C6 OK Fetch completed.<EOL>
```

I've been looking at the [RFC for IMAP][1] and there look like there might be some commands that sound possibly relevant (`RECENT` for example), but I'm not familiar enough with the ins and outs of IMAP to be sure I'm on the right track with this.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-7.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Use `FETCH` with a range of `[$lastSeenHighestUID+1]:*`, per this comment in [RFC 3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501):

> Note: The next unique identifier value is intended to
> provide a means for a client to determine whether any
> messages have been delivered to the mailbox since the
> previous time it checked this value.  It is not intended to
> provide any guarantee that any message will have this
> unique identifier.  A client can only assume, at the time
> that it obtains the next unique identifier value, that
> messages arriving after that time will have a UID greater
> than or equal to that value.

So if the highest UID you saw last was 242, then you would fetch `243:*`.

`RECENT` is [not terribly reliable](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/james-server-dev/200803.mbox/%3C88f6e29a0803210110x2784101crf66e32fd96fd1b7f@mail.gmail.com%3E), because the first client will see the flag then remove the flag. If your code is the unlucky second (or nth >= 2), then you'll never know the message was recent.

Comment: So this just gives new messages, right? It wouldn't let you know about messages deleted by another client app?

Comment: And use UID ranges, the server can tell you about *all* messages at the same time.

Comment: The first client to access the mailbox WILL remove the recent flag, no  "maybe". One way to learn which messages have been deleted is to take the ones you have cached and will display, and issue "uid search uid 1000,1002,1005" (assuming UIDs 1001, 1002 and 1005 are the ones you plan to display from cache). The server then tells you which of the three messages have not been deleted.

Comment: I think you mean: "So if the highest UID you saw last was 242, then you would fetch 243:*." (Use lastseenuid + 1 when fetching)

Comment: @Gigi: Negative. There is no guarantee last + 1 will exist.

Comment: It doesn't have to. You ask for it; if it isn't returned, you needn't take any action. I have seen some desktop email clients do this.